# Why backbone.js events not work

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, binding, components

I recently write a city select component demo using backbone.js. The window.CityModalView events ("click span.confirm": 'confirm') failed. But the window.CityView events("click span.confirm2": 'confirm') works. Can any one tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it? Thank you very much.

The code is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/40phzeqd/

```
<script>
window.CityModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"table",

    initialize:function () {
        var self = this;
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'confirm', 'cancel');
        this.render();

    },

    template: _.template('<div>City Modal</div><div class="modal-content"></div><div class="operator"><span class="confirm">YES</span><span class="cancel">NO</span></div>'),

    events: {
        "click span.confirm": 'confirm',
        "click span.cancel": 'cancel'
    },

    render:function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },

    confirm: function() {
        console.log('YES');
    },

    cancel: function() {
        console.log('NO');
    }


});

window.CityView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'div',

    events: {
        'click span.add-city': 'addCity',
        "click span.confirm2": 'confirm',
        "click span.cancel2": 'cancel'
    },

    initialize:function () {
        var self = this
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'appendItem', 'addCity','confirm', 'cancel');

        this.cityModalView = new CityModalView();
        this.render();
    },

    template: _.template('<div>City List</div><span class="city-selected"></span><span class="add-city">+SET CITY</span><div class="operator"><span class="confirm2">yes</span><span class="cancel2">no</span></div><div class="city-modal-sec hide"></div>'),

    render:function () {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        $('.city-modal-sec', this.el).append(this.cityModalView.render().el);
        return this;
    },

    appendItem: function(item){
        var itemView = new CityItemView({
            model: item
        });
        $('.city-selected', this.el).append(itemView.render().el);
    },

    addCity: function(){
        $('.city-modal-sec').removeClass('hide')
    },

    confirm: function() {
        console.log('confirm');
    },

    cancel: function() {
        console.log('cancel');
    }

});

window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),

    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Initializing Home View');
        this.cityView = new CityView();
        this.render();
    },

    template: _.template('<div class="city-sec"></div>'),

    render:function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        $('.city-sec', this.el).append(this.cityView.render().el);
        return this;
    }

});

var homeView = new HomeView();
```

Comment: Seems to work fine if you include the jQuery, Underscore, and Backbone JavaScript files: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/35gdzrco/

Comment: @muistooshort It renders but the events for the additional view don't fire. Re-delegating works, I'm not sure yet why it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks. The click buttons yes/no in cityView works, but the buttons yes/no in cityModalView fail. That's my concern.

Comment: I'm not exactly why but when you render your *cityView* it's overwriting the events bound for your *cityModelView*, if you either instantiate your *cityModelView* after you render your cityView or just call `delegateEvents` it works.

Comment: Why are you trying to put a `<div>` directly inside a `<table>`? That's not valid HTML so you should fix that. Anyway, you'll have a much better time if you create views the instant you need them and destroy them when you're done with them. Trying to cache and re-use views just makes a big mess of confusion.

Comment: @Jack: jQuery will remove event bindings at various times to help prevent memory leaks, that's often the source of the problem in these cases. Building and destroying views as needed wipes out most event problems in my experience.

Comment: @muistooshort OK, but In this case when the secondView (cityModalView) is created it's el isn't attached to the DOM, so why would it make a difference if it's parent view is rendered or not?

Comment: @Jack: Doesn't matter if it on the page or not, there are still event bindings that will be cleaned up when, for example, you `this.$el.html(...)` multiple times. I'm not sure of the exact source of the problem so I'm not answering; however, creating the views at the moment they're needed and destroying them when you don't need them on the page will probably solve the events problem.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks, creating the view at the time needed definitely solves the problem in this case (I already tested that) and i agree with you that unless you have a reason not to it's probably a better idea to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

As [@muistooshort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) pointed out, if you don't have a reason to cache your views your probably better off creating them as needed and destroying them when your done with them. In this case you are creating a reference to your *cityModalView* in your *cityView* and then rendering your *cityView* which appears to be destroying the *cityModalViews* bound events.

To work around this you can instantiate your cityModalView after your cityView is rendered

```
this.cityModalView = new window.CityModalView();
this.$('.city-modal-sec').append(this.cityModalView.render().el);
```

Or you can just re-[delegate](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) your events after you render your view

```
render:function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    this.$('.city-modal-sec').append(this.cityModalView.render().el);
    this.cityModalView.delegateEvents();
    return this;
},
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29oyu5p3/4/)

Aside from that you can clean up your views a bit by making use of your views jQuery selector function [this.$](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) and cached jQuery object for it's el [this.$el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el). Further in your case your events and functions are already bound to your view so there isn't any reason to be calling `_.bind()` and `self = this`.

Comment: I'd also recommend saying `this.$(selector)` instead of `$(selector, this.el)` and `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)` everywhere, and getting rid of the `var self = this;` and `_.bindAll` cargo stuff.

Comment: @muistooshort I've edited my anwser as per your suggestions. I did notice that at times the OP was using the cached jQuery element `this.$el` but not consistently.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just being picky. That was my up-vote anyway.